# export a concatenated range of valued cells into text file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, text, range

I want to export my concatenated range of valued cells into the text file.
Firstly, I input the data as below

[image: image 1]

Then, I concatenated into the different tab so-called 'Output2' :

[image: image 2]

and the coding so that the value depicted from concatenated cells will be exported into a desired text file as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim filename As String
Dim lineText As String
Dim my_range As Range

filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File EFT" & Format(Now, "_ddmmyy") & ".txt"
Open filename For Output As #1
Set my_range = Worksheets("Output2").Range("B2")
For i = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To my_range.Columns.Count
lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & my_range.Cells(i, j)

Next j
Print #1, lineText

Next i
Close #1

MsgBox ("File is Generated")

End Sub
```

I have a problem now which the text file only appeared at the first line. What I need is, a command which, as and when I input the value, say up to 10 rows, so it will be exported as 10 rows at text file as what I needed and later if I addon another input into 35 rows, the exported text file showing 35 lines

[image: image 3]

Comment: Add a line fin character `lineText = lineText & vbLf`

Comment: Where is the `12020000158717`  and `ICU SELANGOR` in the output file coming from ?

Comment: Toddleson, i just dont get it....where shud i put the lineText = lineText & vbLf?

Comment: `Set my_range = Worksheets("Output2").Range("B2")` is only one cell so print will be only 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ar, n As Long, filename As String
        
    With Sheets("Input")
        ' determine number of rows
        n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    End with

    With Sheets("Output2")
        If n = 0 Then
             MsgBox "No Data", vbCritical
             Exit Sub
        ElseIf n = 1 Then
             ReDim ar(0)
             ar(0) = .Range("B2").Value2
        Else
             ar = Application.Transpose(.Range("B2").Resize(n))
        End If        
    End With
    
    ' text file
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File EFT" & Format(Now, "_ddmmyy") & ".txt"

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(filename)
       .writeline Join(ar, vbCrLf)
       .Close
    End With
   
    MsgBox n & " lines exported to " & filename, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. however it didn't resolved. At the 'output2', i have dragged the selection up to 1000 row so whatever info from my input, will automatically concatenated into 'output2'. however, the exported txt still showing the remaining 1000 rows, which i don't need it

Comment: @EnMustafa what is the name of sheet in image1 ?

Comment: I named it as 'input' and i concatenated the 'input' info into tab 'output2'... If able, i can email to you the file for your review?

Comment: @EnMustafa Ok - see update, I assume output2 has header so first line is B2, If not change `.Range("B2")` in both places to `.Range("B1")`

Comment: wow!...its works finally...thanks CDP1802!! really appreciated it!